# ObservableCollection<T> not updating the UI

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, observablecollection, infragistics

So I have an observable collection that I am updating and I can see the values have changed but the UI is not changing.  Here is what I have

```
public static class GeoLocations
{

    public static ObservableCollection<Station> _locations = new ObservableCollection<Station>();
    public static ObservableCollection<Station> locations
    {
        get { return _locations; }
        set 
        { 
            _locations = value;      
        }
    }
}

public class Station
{
    public int StationNumber { get; set; }
    // Bunch more properties here ...
}
```

Then I have a class that is generating random numbers for all the properties in another thread.  I know that its changing them because when I hover over the items in the chart I'm using I see it updating.  However the chart itself is not updating.  Let say that the first number is 1.6.  Then updates to 1.4 0.5 1.2... The chart remains at 1.6.

The chart I'm using is an Infragistics XamDataChart.  I suspect the problem is the way I've implemented my classes.  I have more UI that need to be updated than just the charts so I'm hoping once I figure this out I can make those work here.

Here is my xaml for the XamDataChart

```
<ig:XamDataChart Style="{StaticResource BarChartStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">

        <ig:XamDataChart.Axes>
            <ig:NumericYAxis x:Name="YAxis" MinimumValue="0" Interval="0.4" Label="{}{}" FontSize="8" MaximumValue="1.7" MajorStroke="#FF2C2C2C" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="White" FontWeight="Bold">
                <ig:NumericYAxis.LabelSettings>
                    <ig:AxisLabelSettings Extent="23" Foreground="White"/>
                </ig:NumericYAxis.LabelSettings>
            </ig:NumericYAxis>
            <ig:CategoryXAxis x:Name="XAxis" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                              Label="{}{IndexNum}" 
                              Interval="1" 
                              MajorStroke="Black" 
                              Foreground="White" 
                              BorderBrush="White"
                              DataContextChanged="CollectionChanged">
                <ig:CategoryXAxis.LabelSettings>
                    <ig:AxisLabelSettings Extent="17" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="11" Foreground="White"/>
                </ig:CategoryXAxis.LabelSettings>
            </ig:CategoryXAxis>
        </ig:XamDataChart.Axes>
        <ig:XamDataChart.Series>

            <ig:ColumnSeries Style="{StaticResource ColumnSeriesStyle}" x:Name="Series1" ValueMemberPath="StationNumber "  XAxis="{Binding ElementName=XAxis}"  YAxis="{Binding ElementName=YAxis}" Brush="DodgerBlue" Outline="Black">

            </ig:ColumnSeries>
        </ig:XamDataChart.Series>
    </ig:XamDataChart>
```

Code Behind

```
XAxis.ItemsSource = GeoLocations.locations;
Series1.ItemsSource = GeoLocations.locations;
```

Comment: If it is your `locations` collection you are trying to bind to then shouldn't  it be `ItemsSource="{Binding locations}"`?

Comment: Oh sorry in the code behind I have XAxis.ItemsSource = GeoLocations.locations; Series1.ItemsSource = GeoLocations.locations;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the properties are being changed on your `Station` objects, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on it, and fire the `PropertyChanged` event in your property setters. It seems like the chart object isn't being notified when your other thread changes the properties. The `ObservableCollection` will only cause an update in the chart when Station objects are added or removed, not when their properties change.

You say that when you hover over the chart you see the updated values, but this may be because the chart is actually calling the getter on the property to display that, so you will see the updated value there (but I'm speculating on this).

Comment: Ohhhh.  I will try this.  What you have said makes sense.  As another way to test this then it sounds like if I removed all the elements of locations and then added new ones that would fire the event in the observable collections that would regenerate the charts.

Comment: Actually I didn't realize that it was only a few lines of code to implement InotifyPropertyChanged.  So I just did that and VIOLA!  My random code is generating too quickly so my chart looks a little crazy but thats easy to fix. I feel so good.